# Symfony2 : assets_base_url by protocol or header 

Tags: ssl, https, symfony, assets

It is possible to set an specific domain when the request contains header(x-forwarded-photo) in assets config ?

Now I have this:

```
framework:
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    templating:
        assets_base_urls:
            http:   [http://a.com]
            ssl:   [https://a.com]
```

I need that to this configuration

cliente -> https -> load balancer -> http -> apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this that solves the issue

- To avoid security issues, HTTP headers coming from proxies are not trusted
- anymore by default (like `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `X_FORWARDED_PROTO`, and
- `X_FORWARDED_HOST`). If your application is behind a reverse proxy, add the

  following configuration:
          framework:
              trust_proxy_headers: true